# Does the transformation into Shazam help heal Billy's injuries?

Tags: dc, comics, dc-extended-universe, shazam, shazam-2019

When an injured Billy Batson transforms into Shazam, it is obvious that Shazam no longer has those injuries. However, when he reverts to Billy Batson, are those injuries healed?

I welcome all answers from the movie **Shazam (2019)**, **comics** and all [available] sources.

Comment: I do remember the DCAU Justice League where Superman and Shazam fought each others. After a while, Shazam was so tired that he relied on using his Shazam scream to hurt Superman with the thunder. However, when he reverted back to the little boy, he looked healthy enough. Though I wonder if it's truly healing, otherwise he could just revert then rechange to heal himself and keep fighting again.

Comment: @Clockwork the movie however contradicts this when Shazam fights Dr Sivana the first time. anyways, in the case you explained, its when Shazam got hurt but Billy was fine. I'm looking for something else. For ex. lets say billy has a fractured arm, when he transforms, his arm will be fine. So what happens when he reverts to Billy again? will the fractured arm be healed?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

On the Shazam wiki it says this:

> Advanced Healing: If he is injured in battle he may call on the magical lightning to heal himself and mend wounds. If wounded, his divine and supernatural energies enable him to recover at other worldly speed. - [Shazam Powers](https://shazam.fandom.com/wiki/Shazam#Powers)

This suggests he is healed when he is struck by the lightning. In the aforementioned fight in DCAU, after he reverts to Billy Batson, Superman covers his mouth so that he cannot say Shazam again.